# Styling a Grid with Fixed Width Cells

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 7 components of a fixed width (256px) and `margin: 20px` and I want them to be aligned in a grid, but I'm trying to get the last item in the last row to always be justified right so it lines up with the column furthest right. I also want the column grid to be centered on the page. I've tried a few things but I've gotten stuck.

I tried doing this with a flex box, and while it's entirely possible I'm missing something about flex boxes that could get this to work, I didn't have any luck. The closest I got was something like:

```
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid div {
   margin: 20px;
   width: 256px;
   height: 48px;
}

.grid div:last-child {
  margin-left: auto
}
```

But the justify-content, while it gets the components centered on the page, also, if the last row has less components than the other rows, centers those components and ruins the grid effect.

I also tried this without a flex box and kind of got close with just:

```
.grid div {
   margin: 20px;
   width: 256px;
   height: 48px;
   float: left;
}

.grid div:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

This is pretty close I'd just need a way to set the width of the grid to be a multiple of 256px (well, 296px because of the margins) and then center the grid in the parent. Totally doable with media-queries but I feel like there should be a more straightforward solution.

(Pictures in case I'm not explaining it well)

Behavior I'm looking for:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5ySx.jpg

Behavior that's not right:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xakgw.jpg

HTML for reference:

```
<div class="grid">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your html, too

Comment: @MichaelCoker added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a couple of media queries you should be able to do this, where you use the pseudo elements as *ghost* elements, and fill the gap between the last and second last item.

<strike>Here I also gave the `grid` a max width, so there can't be 5 in a row, and I did that because if you need that, you'll need an extra element as the second last to act as a *ghost* because it will take 3 *ghost* elements (2 pseudo + 1) to solve that.</strike>

If you need to fit 5 in a row, one simply double the size on one of the pseudo elements, 256px + 256px + 40px ( 40px for the margin ), for 6 in a row, 3 times the width etc.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid div {
   margin: 20px;
   width: 256px;
   height: 48px;
   background: lightgray;
}
  .grid div:last-of-type {
    order: 2
  }

@media screen and (min-width: 592px) {
  .grid::after {
    content: '';
    margin: 20px;
    width: 256px;
    height: 0;
    order: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 888px) {
  .grid::before {
    content: '';
    margin: 20px;
    width: 256px;
    height: 0;
    order: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1184px) {
  .grid::before {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1480px) {
  .grid::before {
    display: inline;
    width: 552px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great solution . I am still trying to get  a solution without media queries; but probably won't get anything that really works

Answer (score 1):

As a proof of how stubborn I am, here is my solution.

The trick is to have a number of elements that is divisible by 2..3..4..5  so add as much extra elements as needed.

Of course, this is so ugly that I have choosen to hide the source code :-(

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.grid div {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 256px;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.grid div:last-of-type {
  background-color: fuchsia;
  order: 3;
  margin-top: -68px;
}

.grid span {
  margin: 0px 20px;
  width: 256px;
  height: 0px;
  order: 2;
}

.grid span:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Beat you on this with 5 min :) ... but I like the fact to not need media query (hopefully). When you have 4 in a row it breaks and does not flow as intended. Is that solvable without media query?

Comment: Of course you did .... :) ... am waiting.. and btw, it breaks on 5 in a row as well

Comment: @LGSon At least I have achieved something that could be called a *solution*

Comment: Ugly, yessss...but I am still impressed by your _stubbornness_ and actually figure a way ... +1